# Split string in JavaScript when there is not a clear separator

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a String in JavaScript that is separated by commas but, I have extra commas within the portions of the string I want to keep together. Here's an example:

```
var str = 'A. This is one part, B. This is the, tricky part., C. Final portion';
```

My desired result is an array like this one:

```
var arrayAfterSplit = [
    'A. This is one part',
    'B. This is the, tricky part',
    'C. Final portion'
];
```

I'm trying with Regex but, no success until now, I'd appreciate any help guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about :

```
 str.split (/, (?=[A-Z]\. )/)
```

Explanation :

the `,` find those characters in source string, the `(?=[A-Z]\. )` then test if the following characters a capital letter followed by a full-stop and a single space. This is a "look ahead" test and the characters there are just checked not matched by the regular expression.

So the string is split by the occurrence of `,` but only if the following characters are a capital letter  etc.

Comment: You're my hero dude, thanks. Could you explain me a little bit what's happening there?

Answer (score 0):

try the Below one

```
(?:,\s+(?=[A-Z]\.))

,\s+ - Comma (,) should be followed by one or more white space 


 (?=[A-Z]\.) positive Look ahead to check the above condition follows by the Capital Letter and (.)
```